# Chance of back-to-back independent events in an ordered set

Tags: probability

I have a fair, six-sided die that has $5$ red faces and one yellow face. I'm going to roll the die $10$ times, and I want to know the probability of that series having two yellows in a row at any point $(1-2, 2-3,... 9-10)$

I'd be thrilled with just an answer to this case and using the rest as an exercise, but I eventually need to extend my answer: I have an $i$-sided die with $j$ yellow faces. If I roll it $N$ times, what are the chances of seeing at least $k$ yellows in a row?

My approach:

There's an ${10 \choose 3}(\frac{1}{6})^3(\frac{5}{6})^7$ chance of my rolls resulting in exactly $3$ yellow faces. Let's call this $P(3)$. There are ${10 \choose 3}$ ways for those yellows to be ordered, but I don't know how to count how many of those ways are back-to-back without duplicates. If I knew that number, $nnd$, my chances of having back-to-back yellows if I KNOW I have three yellows is $\frac{nnd}{{10 \choose 3}}$. If I don't know how many yellows I have, my chance of rolling back-to-back yellows and having three total yellows is:

$P(3)=\frac{nnd}{{10 \choose 3}}$

$nCr(10,3)$ cancels out when eventually reduced, but since I can't determine nnd I haven't bothered cancelling out yet. If I could get $nnd$ figured out without manually listing and counting, I could do the above equations for $ 2, 3, ... 10$ yellow faces, I think. So my chances overall are:

$nnd(\text{expressed as an equation of n})\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{10} (\frac{1}{6})^n(\frac{1}{6})^{n-10}$

My approach to solving nnd, conceptually, was to anchor the back-to-back losses at a specific position and count the possible results around that position (so ${8}\choose{n-2}$), but that would double-count results that have back-to-back yellows in two places, such as YYRRYYRRRR

Comment: I'm assuming that rolling 3 or more counts as rolling 2

Comment: That's a correct assumption, so RRYYYRRRRR would count as successfully rolling an instance of back-to-back